# How to access things in postproccessing from scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

Hello I have bean making my game and I created a booster for my car and I want to have vignette effect when I step on it, I don't know how to make a script to get the post processing and change the vignette thing.
Thanks!

Comment: Unity says it best with their _[Controlling effects using scripts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0/manual/Manipulating-the-Stack.html)_, part of the **Post Processing Stack v2**.

Comment: @MickyD The question is specifically about volume in Unity URP, not PostProcess Stackv2

Comment: @MickyD The component vignette effect is dependent of volume class in URP. OP knows what volume means sir. Take a look at this part of the tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7zg3JhLhI8).

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: @MickyD *I don't know how to make a script to get the post processing and change the vignette thing. Thanks!* Read the question carefully, sir.

Comment: @MickyD PostProcess Stack v2 works in a unity built-in , not in URP. Are you familiar with URP sir? when OP says to change the post-process in URP, it means to get the component in Volume. I do not know where you found the post-process stackv2 question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to get the volume parameters in **URP** and **HDRP** are similar to each other, in the following code, after entering the desired volume in the hierarchy, you can carefully see the names of the components mounted on the volume at start.

```cs
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition; // .Universal for urp

///...

public Volume volume;

public void Start()
{
    volume.profile.components.ForEach(c => Debug.Log(c.GetType().Name)); // displays the volumes components name, for e.g: Fog, HDRISKY, Bloom
}
```

Now in the variable change method, all you have to do is get the component via `TryGet` and change the value.

```cs
if (volume.profile.TryGet(out Vignette vignette)) // for e.g set vignette intensity to .4f
{
    vignette.intensity.value = .4f;
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) don't use LINQ in a game 2) its much more efficient (not to mention follows _how_ Unity is meant to be used.  i.e.  be useful to the Editor) to use `[SerializeField] private ...` or a `public` member than perform a late-bound search.

Comment: @MickyD Linq is not used here. (The first part of answer is Optional, I wrote in the description to find the names of the components! It can delete it after the log.) This question is not related to public and private. Arguably the most concise solution to solving and understanding the problem is the best.

Comment: Ah, well I wouldn't use late-search techniques regardless.

Comment: Do you know any free water assets that are for URP not normal all my water assets cant be loaded because they are not compatable in URP

Comment: @EpixEpoc Check out Unity's awesome [Boat Attack tech demo](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/BoatAttack) using **URP** on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, how to make the fading and fading effect of UI objects glowing?

For example, there is a sprite picture with a halo of the moon.

[image]

We can add a CanvasGroup component to it.

[image]

The alpha value on the component controls the transparency of the image, from 0 to 1.

Then we can achieve the glowing halo effect by controlling the change of the Alpha value cycle in the code.

Here is the code:

```
private CanvasGroup moonCanvasGroup;
private float flashSpeed=0.2f;
private bool isOn = true;
private float maxAlpha = 0.6f;
private float minAlpha = 0.05f;

    void Start () 
   {
      moonCanvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }

      void Update () 
     {
        if (moonCanvasGroup.alpha < maxAlpha && isOn)
       {
          moonCanvasGroup.alpha +=flashSpeed* Time.deltaTime;
       }
       else 
      {
           isOn = false;
           moonCanvasGroup.alpha -=flashSpeed* Time.deltaTime;
           if (moonCanvasGroup.alpha <minAlpha)
       {
           isOn = true;
       }
     }
 }
```

Then mount the script on the picture, and the effect of the moon glowing is completed.